# How should i implement this constructor to workalong side a method which reads CSV files?

Tags: java

I haven't implement any code as of yet as I'm confused on how to approach this problem.

I have been asked to implement a constructor which should initialise the time and level fields using a given string from a CSV file. Then this constructor should create `Measurement` objects in the method which reads in CSV files?

Anyone have any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: You approach the problem by writing some code. You already have an idea of what to do. You wrote about needing "a constructor which should intialise the time and level fields using a given string from the CSV file." So how about starting with that? Stop being afraid to make mistakes -- code can be refactored or even thrown out if necessary. If you aren't making mistakes, you aren't learning.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Constructor in the Measurement Object that takes a String(), then parse this to set your instance variables.

Hey presto! the code that is reading through the CSV can create your Measurement objects from each line,

Comment: Thanks! When you say it takes a string.. do you mean i should also include my code their which reads the CSV file? Also i would i parse this to set vairables?

Comment: You would need to read the csv elsewhere to create this comma separated String to initialise the Measurement, you couldn't pass the csv in this scenario as the Constructor would would return 1 instance of a Measurement.

Comment: As Antix said though - It's not a great way of doing things, parsing the String into seperate values doesn't really belong in the Measurement object, but if that's your brief, the answer I have given will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion for the problems like this, where I have to read data from some data source (in your case CSV) and using data I have to construct/initialise the attributes of the object. I will **NOT USE CONSTRUCTOR**, rather  I will create a factory method inside the class and use that method.

Steps that I will follow

- Mark constructors private to stop construction through the constructor.
- Create a factory method inside the class like createXXX() or getXXX() or create an inner class as factory class that has a method.
- Write code to read file inside the method and then call private constructor and initialize inside constructor (Here you can also choose to initialise inside method only)

This way you will ensure that you Read from CSV is successfully and even throw an exception if fail to do that (as it is always disgraced to throw an exception from constructors).

Comment: It's actually part of my brief where i have to use a constructor to initialise unfortunately!

Comment: Ok! I will suggest discussing with your architect, is there any challenge using factory method?

Comment: You can have a private method that do the reading and call that inside your constructor.